# Finalizing a custom TraceListener with autoflush='false' (C#, .net)

Tags: c#, .net, configuration, trace

I'm writing a custom tracelistener to write trace messages to a file adding rotation (for example changing the file name each day).
In the override of the `Flush` method, I call `Flush` on the underlying `StreamWriter`, but if I set `autoflush='false'` in the application configuration, `Flush` does not get called when the application is terminated.

What is the correct method to finalize a custom trace listener when the application exits?

EDIT: I overrode the `Dispose(bool disposing)` method, since the base `TraceListener` class already implements the disposable pattern, but, as far as I can say, the method is not called. If I implement an explicit destructor, the destructor is called, but at that point I shouldn't assume that the stream reference is still valid, right?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

if your software does not call to Trace.Close on termination then you cannot ensure any flush is done.
See [this article](https://web.archive.org/web/20200111044134/http://geekswithblogs.net:80/akraus1/articles/81629.aspx) for more details.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest that you do this in the dispose method of your custom `TraceListener` class just before you close the underlying `StreamWriter`.

Answer (score 0):

You should override the `Close` method in your custom tracelistener, and `Flush` and `Dispose` your underlaying `StreamWriter` there.